# Start Office add-in locked

Tags: ms-office, excel-addins

Can I set an Office add-in to start locked similar to how a user can do that manually by clicking the header of the app and selecting Lock from the menu? I need to save space from the add-in title area, which is not needed in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a property for that but after you launch it and you save the document with its add-in in a locked state, it will remember that.